# PHPDocumentor @example usage

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I can not seem to understand how to get PHPCocumentor2 `@example` tags to work correctly.

I am attempting to parse a single file.  My working directory is `/home/developers/domains/example.com` and I am trying to parse (relative to my working directory) `simplesamlphp/modules/example/lib/Auth/Process/RoleTrigger.php`.  This class file has a DocBloc that looks like:

```
/**
 * Trigger Role on User from Configuration.
 *
 * @example "RoleManager.usage.example.php" Test Example
 */
public function process() { /* ... */ }
```

When I run the command to parse just this file in maximum verbosity (`phpdoc -f simplesamlphp/modules/example/lib/Auth/Process/RoleTrigger.php -t httpdocs/test -vvv`) PhpDoc indicates that the current project root is `/home/developers/domains/example.com/simplesamlphp/modules/example/lib/Auth/Process/`, so, according to the Documentation, this indicates that the example file `RoleManager.usage.example.php` should be located either at the same directory level of the parsed file, or in the `examples` directory of the current Project Root (which would be `/home/developers/domains/example.com/simplesamlphp/modules/example/lib/Auth/Process/examples/`).

However, try as I might, I can not seem to get the Example to show up in the generated documentation.

All I seem to get is, on the right-hand side of the generated page:

```
Tags
example     Test Example
```

With no hyper-link, or display of the file contents, or anything.  Just the "Description" with nothing else.

I have attempted to use `<code>` but multiple lines with multiple levels render broken html that is also useless:

This:

```
/**
 * Test Doc
 *
 * <code>
 * <?php
 * $array = array(
 *     1 => 'one',
 *     2 => 'two',
 * );
 * print_r($array);
 * ?>
 * </code>
 */
```

Renders the following HTML:

```
<p><code>
&lt;?php
$array = array(</p>
<pre><code>1 =&gt; 'one',
2 =&gt; 'two',</code></pre>
<p>);
print_r($array);
?>
</code></p>
```

Multiple nested `<code>` and `<pre>` tags that render something awful.  But that is a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I initially posted this question, it happens that the `@example` tag was not implemented (yet) in PHPDocumentor v2.  This is an unfortunate truth for a number of tags as PHPDocumentor v2 is built on top of a completely different foundation than v1, and tags were/are still being ported to the new system.

Shortly after I posted the question I checked in with the Git community working on the project and contributed a little to the task of implementing the `@example` tag.

At this time, the tag works as expected and defined in the PHPDoc documentation, to the T (so far as I can test).

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/example.html

It does occur to me that, as this now works as expected, this question (and answer) are likely no longer needed.  However I wanted to make sure that I updated it lest someone stumble upon it and become confused.

For completeness sake, at the time of writing, the syntax executes as follows:

```
/**
 * @example [location] [<start-line> [<number-of-lines>] ] [<description>]
 */

/**
 * Or inline {@example [location] [<start-line> [<number-of-lines>] ] [<description>]}
 */
```